# Is the split in pronunciation of "detail" regional, semantic, or irrelevant?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Or maybe just haphazard? Something else?

When I want to refer to a small military unit put together to carry out a specific task, I'll call it a **DEtail**, accent on the first syllable.

When I want to refer to a particular portion of a larger whole, I'll call it a **deTAIL**, emphasis on the *second* syllable.

In my mind, in other words, there is a semantic difference between the pronunciations. Nevertheless, I have noticed that some speakers of American English tend to stress the first syllable, and some don't. Is there any rhyme or reason to the variation in pronunciation of this word?

Comment: Cisatlantically the verb in the sense 'set forth details' is ordinarily stressed on the second syllable, so it is possible that some of us govern our pronunciation by analogy with those disyllabic words in which the stress distinguishes noun from verb - eg, *record*, *import*, *decrease*

Comment: My pronunciation is roughly the same as yours, though I'm sure I've noticed folks who pronounce them differently.  Frankly, it's the sort of, uh, detail that I'd ignore, unless really far afield.

Comment: I've always wondered if there's a word for that -- where there are two different scans of a word, which tend to be used in different ways -- detail is a great example.

Comment: purely one man's opinion, there is a semantic difference, as you say.  i feel it has less do with region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought is that I would tend to use DE-tail as a noun and de-TAIL as a verb, usually in the past tense.

> That's an irrelevant DE-tail.
>
> She de-TAILED her problems for us at great length.

However, I don't see any backup for this in the dictionary, so it must be regional (or familial!) for me.  In fact, the accent on the second syllable seems to be the preferred pronunciation--since it's listed first.  (That's still the custom, right?)

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detail

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is personal preference influenced by locality, culture, and conversational context.  For example, the word *envelope* can have two different pronunciations in American English: one where the *en-* portion can have a French-like pronunciation:

> *ON-velope*

and another that uses the strict English pronunciation of *en-*, which sounds like the letter *n*.  My mother prefers the French-like pronunciation; I prefer the strict English pronunciation.  We're from the same family of people who grew up in the same area of the country, and we pronounce it differently.

In the UK, I have heard people add letters to words where no such letters exist.  For example, to pronounce the word:

> *aluminum*

some British people will make the *u* a strict letter pronunciation and add an *i* where none exists:

> *al-yoo-MIN-ee-um* (as if the word were spelled *alyuminium*)

Most Americans pronounce *aluminum* with the stress on the second syllable and do not add a letter:

> *al-OOM-i-num*

Another word that gets interesting treatment by the British is:

> *lieutenant*

A British person can pronounce *lieutenant* where the first *t* sounds more like an *f*:

> *LEUF-ten-ant*

An American will use a hard *t* and stress the second syllable:

> *lieu-TEN-ant*

Canandians and Americans pronounce the letter combination *ou* in some words differently.  An American can pronounce *ou* as if the *u* sounded like a *w*:

> house: *HOW-se*
>
> about: *a-BOWT*

A Canadian can make the *ou* sound like the *ou* in *soup*:

> house: *HOUW-se*
>
> about: *a-BOUWT* or *a-BOOT*

Oddly enough, Americans and Canadians pronounce *soup* the same way.

So pronouncing *detail* as *DE-tail* or *de-TAIL* is matter of preference.  As long as people understand that *detail* in one context is similar to *detail* in another context, it doesn't matter a great deal how it is pronounced.

Comment: Both "aluminium" and "aluminum" are accepted by IUPAC as standard spellings, it's just regional preferences. http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/news/IUPAC_Periodic_Table-1May13.pdf

Comment: Cool!  I learn something new everyday.